# What is difference between Street Photography and Travel Photography?

Tags: terminology, travel, street-photography

Can anyone explain what the difference is between Street Photography and Travel Photography?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travel photography can encompass street photography but it may also include many other types of photography as well: landscapes, architectural, environmental portraits that go beyond a street scene, wildlife, indoor scenes at tourist attractions, museums, or historical locations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Street photography ∈ Travel photography (at least I understand it this way).

Travel photography is about landscapes, people, architecture, air shots, nature, animal, all aspects of travel. Street photography is part of it.

Street photography is more about shooting daily life situations, showing the expression and real atmosphere of city, place you're living/visiting. It's more about capturing moments than places.

I think that the best place to get inspire when it comes to travel and street photography is Photler.com - go to http://photler.com/inspire, browse some of their hand-picked galleries and you'll quickly get the difference :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, smells like homework but okay.

For me, travel photography is trying to tell the story of the place, geographically, through nature, through landmarks and buildings and attractions and through photos that show off the environment or the city.
Street photography, is really a study in people and moments. Street photography isn't called so just because a lot of the famous examples occur on the street - it's because it captures a moment of feeling. Candid photography without the tripod, conducted for enquiry. It that features unmediated chance encounters, once-in-a-lifetimes and random incidents within the public world we all call home. It can even consist of objects or the imprint of someone sitting in the snow - anything distinctly human.

TL;DR -- Travel is the place, Street is the human element.

Hope this helps!